# Wireless still does not work 12.04 Dell Dimension 3000

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I have tried many solutions found in aksubuntu, but no luck in getting the wireless to work on this computer. The wired connection works. Below is the wireless information.

```
01:01.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02) 
    Subsystem: Linksys WMP54GS v1.1 802.11g Wireless-G PCI Adapter with SpeedBooster 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22 
    Memory at feafe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K] 
    Kernel driver in use: wl 
    Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

All available updates were downloaded and installed 09/01/13. The b43 cutter and installer were tried and the placing of the '#' in front of the blacklisted bcm43xx has been tried (# bcm43xx). Hardinfo was installed also. I am new to Linux, but I am determined to learn all that I can to get this computer fully functional on this os.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Chris! You said "I have tried many solutions found on AskUbuntu". Please, always mention the links to the questions or the exact steps you have taken, to avoid others providing you with a solution that you've already tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ethernet connection then please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe -r ssb
sudo modprobe ssb
sudo modprobe b43
```

This should be blacklisted.

```
blacklist bcm43xx
```

Edit: Also

```
blacklist wl
```

Comment: I have done the above instructions. sudo modprobe b43 is supposed to turn the driver on? I unplugged the ethernet cable, but no wireless. I can supply a copy of the results of the above instructions if that is necessary.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: I have done the above instructions. Here is the link: /home/trpbuktoreed/wireless_script. Also, chmod read: chmod: cannot access 'wireless': No such file or directory.

Comment: Did you run the command all at once? You copy the whole thing then hit enter and it will create wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz file in your home folder. Then paste the file on pastebin.com and the link here.

Comment: Yes, I did run it all at once. I copied it and pasted it and ran it a second time; it looks correct now and the link is: /home/trpbuktoreed/wireless-info.txt

Comment: The link is not click-able, I suspect you can only access it on your computer. Open the file then click on http://pastebin.com/ and paste the contents of the file there then post the link to the file from pastebin here. Thanks

Comment: I made an error in the first time I ran it. Also, you may rather have this link as an url: http://pastebin.com/V7qxvqP4

Comment: I open the file and copied the contents and then pasted it, submitted it to pastebin.com. Here is the url: http://pastebin.com/knRb8xbn

Comment: I edited the answer a little, please try it now. You still have the wl driver and it is the wrong driver for your device. Please post all the output from those commands to pastebin so we can see if there is any error's then post the link here. Thanks

Comment: I copied from the terminal to pastebin; the terminal seems to hang on the sudo modprobe instructions. Here is the url: http://pastebin.com/hHLLX3Z2

Comment: Post `lsmod` to pastebin please.

Comment: I have run lsmod; the url is: http://pastebin.com/YX7VC7HL

Comment: Have you blacklisted the wl driver? Please try one more time I added a little more commands. It should work if it does not then I am out of ideas.

Comment: @gertvdijk, this is not a duplicate of the 3.8 kernel he is using the 3.2 kernel. Thanks

Comment: I have added the blacklist wl line and removed the # in front of the blacklist bcm43xx; there are 2 blacklist lines and saved; rebooted with ethernet cable out. Wireless is working though it still shows connecting to pastebin, though pastebin window displays. Ran lsmod and pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/S8EtnBfG. Check it to see if all is right. Will this work with a TP-Link Archer C7 router (not my router, but in an office)?

Comment: Reboot and see if the wl driver stops loading if not we will have to try another method. It should connect to another router but it depends on the settings.

Comment: Rebooted and wireless is working with this website and pastebin loaded. I guess the wl driver has stopped loading? Ran lsmod; looks different again; here is the url: http://pastebin.com/3G1b7C2d

Comment: Looks good! If it will let you please accept this answer so it will help other people. Thanks